# How to deploy springboot application with google cloud build (compilation on git pushes)?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Can someone tell me how to configure automatic deployment of springboot appilcation stored on github ?

I tried some solution from stack over flow but it is not working. 
My app.yaml file looks like

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk11
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '/workspace/src/main/resources/app.yaml']
```

And the error I am having:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

First, the openJKD11 runtime config doesn't exist for AppEngine Flexible. You have to use a custom runtime like this:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Then, you have to build an container image of your code. You can use a standard `Dockerfile` at your project root like this one

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build a release artifact.
RUN mvn package 

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11

COPY --from=builder /app/target/java-*.jar /java.jar

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dserver.port=${PORT}","-jar","/java.jar"]
```

*Change the `java-*.jar` of this line `COPY --from=builder /app/target/java-*.jar /java.jar` according with the name of your JAR*

And in your Cloud Build, simply deploy your app

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

**Additional remark**

Your previous Cloud Build couldn't work, because your jar file was in `target/` directory and not in the root directory, and your deployment didn't find it. For this, you could add a `dir` param in your Cloud Build

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '/workspace/src/main/resources/app.yaml']
  dir: "target"
```

But the next error would be the runtime openjdk11 not supported.

Comment: When I am trying to go with your instruction I get an error: 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) A custom runtime must have exactly one of [Dockerfile] and [cloudbuild.yaml] in the source directory; [/workspace] contains both
Edit: I had to move cloudbuild to another folder and change it's path in Cloud Build trigger.

Comment: My bad.... Rename your `cloudbuild.yaml` file to something else. Then, when you use Cloud Build, specify the file to use `gcloud builds submit --config=<newCloudBuid>.yaml`. Same thing in the UI (if you use trigge), you can specify the file to use for the build.